# How to add some more HTML after PHP?

Tags: php, html, database

I want to put the **buttons** right below the **table**, which I retrieve from database using **PHP**. But I don't know how to put the buttons below as they keep appearing above the table.

---

```
<html>
<body bgcolor="#E6E6FA"><center>
<h2>Existing Librarian System Access Profile</h2><br><br>
<?php
$hostid= 'localhost';
$user='root';
$pass='';
$db= 'projectdata';
$con = mysqli_connect($hostid, $user, $pass,$db);
mysqli_select_db($con,$db);


$query = "SELECT librarian_id, username, name, ic_no, phone_no, date_created, date_update FROM Librarian";
$run=mysqli_query($con, $query);
            $num_rows=mysqli_num_rows($run);

            if($run===FALSE){
                die(mysql_error());
            }

            if($num_rows>0)
            {
                echo "<table><tr><th>Librarian ID</th><th>Username</th><th>Name</th><th>National ID No</th><th>Phone No</th><th>Date Created</th><th>Date Update</th>";
                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run))
                {   

                $librarian_id=$row['librarian_id'];
                $username=$row['username'];
                $name=$row['name'];
                $id_no=$row['ic_no'];
                $phone_no=$row['phone_no'];
                $date_created=$row['date_created'];
                $date_update=$row['date_update'];

                echo "<tr><td>$librarian_id</td><td>$username</td><td>$name</td><td>$id_no</td><td>$phone_no</td><td>$date_created</td><td>$date_update</td></tr>";
                }
            }?><input type="submit" name="add" value="Add Librarian"><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete Librarian"></center></body></html>
```

Comment: A side note. You can't use mysql_* functions and mysqli_* functions interchangeably.

Comment: You havent closed your tr tags for header and havnt closed table tag. Typos?

Comment: There are typos (mysql_ and mysqli_) . Without closing table tag ,my data are well arranged in their table position. And I don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
<html>
<body bgcolor="#E6E6FA"><center>
<h2>Existing Librarian System Access Profile</h2><br><br>
<table>
<tr><th>Librarian ID</th><th>Username</th><th>Name</th><th>National ID No</th><th>Phone No</th><th>Date Created</th><th>Date Update</th>




<?php
$hostid= 'localhost';
$user='root';
$pass='';
$db= '';
$con = mysqli_connect($hostid, $user, $pass,$db);
mysqli_select_db($con,$db);


$query = "SELECT librarian_id, username, name, ic_no, phone_no, date_created, date_update FROM Librarian";
$run=mysqli_query($con, $query);
            $num_rows=mysqli_num_rows($run);

            if($run===FALSE){
                die(mysql_error());
            }

            if($num_rows>0)
            {

                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run))
                {   

              $librarian_id=$row['librarian_id'];
                $username=$row['username'];
                $name=$row['name'];
                $id_no=$row['ic_no'];
                $phone_no=$row['phone_no'];
                $date_created=$row['date_created'];
                $date_update=$row['date_update'];
?>
</tr>

<tr> <td><?php echo $librarian_id;?></td><td><?php echo $username;?></td><td><?php echo $name;?></td><td><?php echo $id_no;?></td><td><?php echo $phone_no;?></td><td><?php echo $date_created;?></td><td><?php echo $date_update;?></td></tr>


                <?php
                }
            }?>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add Librarian"><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete Librarian"></center></body></html>
```

Comment: I have try your codes, and the buttons are well placed under the table..but the data from the database didn't enter the table. every row in the table just  $librarian_id $username $name $id_no $phone_no $date_created $date_update

Comment: you need to add your dbname under the dbname in connection then only the connection establish

Comment: if its working then please upvote and check this as right.Thanx in advance

Comment: Zero reputation, i can't vote, right? Or how to do it?

Comment: You can atleast tick right to my answer as you asked this question so you have the privilege to mark it as right answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "<tr><td>$librarian_id</td><td>$username</td><td>$name</td><td>$id_no</td><td>$phone_no</td><td>$date_created</td><td>$date_update</td></tr>";
                }
           echo '<tr><td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"add\" value=\"Add Librarian\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"delete\" value=\"Delete Librarian\"></td></tr></table></center></body></html> }?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have not closed tr tag in header using `</tr>`.You have also not closed table tag `</table>` after generating table rows.

Answer (score -1):

You have missed at least one HTML tag. Coppy your HTML into [this](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html) tool to see all HTML errors.